# HTML/CSS - Centering rows of images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty sure this question has been asked before - but I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS and haven't been able to get my images to center looking at the other answers.

As you can see in the image below, I have stacks of test images that I can't get to be centered within their own little columns. There's probably an easy fix - would anyone know what it is?

[image: What it currently looks like]

Here is the code for the -pokemon- tab (center of image), where would I add the styling to make it center? (sorry for the 10 lines of the same image - they're test images for now)

```html
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8); padding-top: 10px;">
        <h2 style="text-align: center">-pokemon-</h2>
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">

    </div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"` should work. If you want your container of images to be center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<img>`'s are inline elements, thus affected by a simple `text-align: center;` which is also defined in a bootstrap class called `text-center`.

Simply add this class to `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2> .... </div>`

```html
    <div class="text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-2" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8); padding-top: 10px;">
        <h2 style="text-align: center">-pokemon-</h2>
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">
        <img src="Spr_5b_289.png">

    </div>
```

This snippet won't work, because it doesn't contain bootstrap's pre-defined CSS rules, but copying it should fix it.

Comment: I was putting the text-center in the style part and not the class part - im so stupid. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-center` class to the div.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8); padding-top: 10px;">
...
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting

```
text-align: center
```

on the container?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.col-md-4 col-md-offset-2{
width:90%;
margin:0 5%;
display:block;
float:left;
}
.col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 img{
dispaly:block;
text-align:center;
}

</style>
```